# Проблема с запуском руби скриптов из приложения

Tags: c#

Есть код:

```
private void runToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var psi = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = "ruby.exe",
            Arguments = __FileName,
            UseShellExecute = false

        };

        var p = Process.Start(psi);

        p.WaitForExit();


    }
```

При запуске руби скрипта (__FileName), если скрипт содержит ошибки, окно сразу закрывается, не давая прочитать, что же там за ошибки. Пробовал делать так:

```
private void runToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        var psi = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = "ruby.exe",
            Arguments = __FileName,
            //RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            RedirectStandardError = true,
            UseShellExecute = false

        };

        var p = Process.Start(psi);

        p.WaitForExit();

        textBox.Text = p.StandardError.ReadToEnd();


    }
```

Но тогда скрипты содержащие "gets" закрываются не давая ничего ввести. Помогите пожалуйста. Заранее благодарю.

Comment: А зачем вам ошибки? Вы запускаете свой скрипт или пользовательский?

Comment: Попробуйте установить RedirectStandardInput в false.

Comment: Ну и может быть такое поведение нормально. Какая ошибка происходит в скриптах?

Comment: H:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- Qt4 (LoadError)
 from H:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
 from H:/Projects/Ruby/AutoDeduction/5.rb:10:in `<main>'

Comment: Ну так тут `gets` не при чём, у вас весь скрипт не запускается. Правьте вопрос.

Comment: этот да, а если взять другой - исправный, с "gets", то он не останавливается на ввод.

Comment: И вы запускаете его **точно так же**? И ошибок **точно** нет? И в stdout **точно** ничего нет?

Comment: да, точно также, ошибок нет

Comment: А что делает gets? Не пишет ли он на консоль что-нибудь?

Comment: скрипт состоит из одной строчки - "gets", но это я думаю не существенно

Comment: и при его работе, окно консоли открывается и сразу же закрывается.

Comment: это может быть существенно. уберите `RedirectStandardOutput = true` и проверьте

Comment: если вызывать его программно, из кода который был приведен выше

Comment: если убрать строки `RedirectStandardOutput = true;` и `RedirectStandardError = true;` то скрипт отрабатывает нормально, но окно с ошибкой появляется и сразу же исчезает

Comment: Собственно вопрос, как заставить окно с ошибкой не исчезать

Comment: Еще раз повторю, если убрать строки RedirectStandardOutput = true; и RedirectStandardError = true; то скрипт содержащий "gets" отрабатывает нормально, но скрипт с ошибкой при своей работе показывает и сразу закрывает окно с ошибкой. Как сделать чтобы это окно не закрывалось, а давало себя прочитать?

Answer (score 1):

Пример вызова ruby.exe для выполнения `puts "Hello, " + gets` из файла test.rb:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
var p = new Process();
p.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
p.ErrorDataReceived += (s, e) => Console.WriteLine("ERROR: " + e.Data);
p.OutputDataReceived += (s, e) => Console.WriteLine("RUBY: %O" + e.Data);
p.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Ruby1.9.3\bin\ruby.exe";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = @"C:\Temp\test.rb";
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
p.Start();
p.StandardInput.WriteLine("world");   // передаем строку в ruby в gets
while (p.StandardError.Peek() >= 0)    
   Console.WriteLine("RUBY.ERROR: " + p.StandardError.ReadToEnd());
while (p.StandardOutput.Peek() >= 0)    
   Console.WriteLine("RUBY: " + p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
p.WaitForExit();
```

Выводит `RUBY: Hello, world`

Comment: Результат тот же, к сожалению.

Comment: Ошибку читает, но скрипты содержащие "gets" не останавливает на ввод.

Comment: _" скрипты содержащие "gets" не останавливает на ввод"_ -- надо указать RedirectStandardInput=true

Comment: добавил, но ничего написать в консоль не получается:(

Comment: Если вам нетрудно, можете привести код, я бы привел свой, но не знаю, как это сделать - вопрос уже задан, а в комментариях этого сделать нельзя.

Comment: _"можете привести код"_ -- тут кажется проблема с ruby.exe; если открыть командную строку (cmd.exe) и запустить ruby.exe, то он ничего не делает. но `ruby.exe -e 'puts "test"'` -- работает. также работает вызов `ruby.exe c:\temp\test.rb"`

Comment: Да, через командную строку все работает, я не об этом, мне нужно чтобы работало через WinForms. Чтобы запускалось, если ошибок нет, и выводило ошибки, если они есть. Пока работает либо первое, либо второе, но не вместе.

Comment: добавил код в ответ.

Comment: Выводить-то она выводит, а вот ввести (если написать в скрипте "gets") ничего не дает (окно открывается и сразу же закрывается).

Comment: _"(если написать в скрипте "gets") ничего не дает"_ -- надо было добавить RedirectStandardInput = true; и т.д. -- добавил в ответ.

Comment: Прошу простить меня, если я чего-то делаю не так, но у меня все равно почему-то не работает, не работает именно ввод (т.е. программа не дает ничего ввести)

Comment: какая версия .net и ruby? я проверял в Visual Studio 2015 в C# Interactive. попробуйте проверить у себя мой код как он есть. только путь к ruby.exe замените на свой.

Comment: У Вас скрипт останавливается на gets и ожидает ввода?

Comment: Я запускаю скрипт в котором только одна строка - "gets", и он не приглашает на ввод - окно сразу же закрывается.

Comment: _"запускаю скрипт в котором только одна строка - "gets""_ -- а если в файле указать `puts "Hello, " + gets` работает?

Comment: Нет, не работает, нет приглашения на ввод, окно в которое нужно вводить сразу же закрывается

Comment: Да, может это существенно, Ваш код у меня отрабатывается при нажатии на кнопку в меню формы

Comment: _"Нет, не работает"_ -- вы запускаете процесс из WinForms приложения? возможно, что проблема из-за thread apartment. чтобы понять в чем причина создайте Console Application. в Main добавьте код из моего ответа.

Comment: _"Ваш код у меня отрабатывается при нажатии на кнопку"_ -- т.е. ruby вызывается, он получает и возвращает данные? если да, то значит Console Application создавать не надо. и тему можно закрыть.

Comment: Нет, код не работает, сейчас попробую создать консольное приложение

Comment: В окне что-то пишется (в проекте winforms не писалось ничего), но окно тут же закрывается.

Comment: _"окно тут же закрывается"_ -- вместо F5 для запуска, нажмите Ctrl+F5. другой способ: в код перед return из Main добавьте Console.ReadLine();

Comment: Все равно "gets" не работает, я уж и не знаю что делать.

Comment: а для чего нужен просто `gets` без какого-либо другого кода? из c# в gets передается строка. и все. делать больше ничего не надо, т.е. не надо ничего выводить. поэтому ruby прекращает работу. и в c# ничего не передается. а если указать puts, то данные выводится в c#.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33036/discussion-between-eugene-and-stack).

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33085/discussion-on-answer-by-stack-------).